# awk: remove multiple tabs between each fields and output a line where each field is separated by a single tab

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have a file whose 11th line should in theory have 1011 columns yet it looks like there are more than 1 tabs between each of its field. More specifically,
If I use

```
awk '{print NF}' file
```

then I can see that the 11th line has the same number of fields as all the rest (except for the first ten lines, which have a different format. That's expected).
But if I use

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"} {print NF}' file
```

I can see that the 11th line has 2001 fields. Based on that, I suspect some of its fields are separted by more than one whitespaces.
I'd like to have each field separated by 1 tab only, so I tried

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} {print}' file > file.modified
```

However, this doesn't solve the problem as

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"} {print NF}' file.modified
```

still indicates that the 11th line has 2001 fields.
Can anyone point out a way to achieve my goal? Thanks a lot! I have put the first 100 lines of my file in the following google drive link.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qOjzjUnJKJpc4VpDxwKPBcqMS7MUuyKy/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 4):

To squeeze multiple tabs to one tab, you could use `tr`:

```
tr -s '\t' <file >file.modified
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help with GNU awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t+"; OFS="\t"} {$1=$1; print}' file
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: This works! Thanks. BTW, can you explain a little bit what does when do we need $1=$1 here?

Comment: `$1=$1` forces `awk` to rebuild the current row with new output field separator (OFS).